# Expand Inner div height to meet the outer div height

Tags: html, css

I want to change the inner div height according to the outer div.
In my case I have two inner divs one with fixed height and the outer div expands its heigh according to that (I use 'clearfix' there). But I need the other inner div also change its height to the outer div height 
height : 100%; did not work.
This is a JsFiddle link to show my problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/qjsqxk7j/18/

HTML ->

```
<div class="outer clearfix">
  <div class="col-xs-3 left">
  </div> 
  <div class="col-xs-9 right">
  <div class="inner">
    <label>sssss</label>
    <button class="btn-default">
      sss
    </button>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS ->

```
.right {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;      
}
.left {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;

}
.inner{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.outer {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    max-width : 500px; 
}
```

Actually I want the Blue div take all the yellow space left and the button and label comes to its vertical centre.
(I want my outer div to get one of its inner div height and changed accordingly.And then when the outer div height changes the other inner div also has to change its height. But it won't.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/qjsqxk7j/32/)**

i used `display:table-cell` on the 2 columns ( left and right ) and `display:table` to `.outer` . for this to work you need to overwrite the `float:left` from the columns given by bootstrap

code added

```
.left,.right {  
display:table-cell;
float:none;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.outer {  
display: table; 
}
```

or with a little **JQ : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/qjsqxk7j/30/)**

code :

```
var hgt = $(".outer").height()
$(".left").height(hgt)
```

let me know if this was what you were looking for

Comment: partially yes. It removes the vertical centre alignment of the inner elements. My final output should be like this
 https://jsfiddle.net/qjsqxk7j/31/ 
But I'll try with your suggestions.

Comment: just add ` vertical-align:middle;` to `.left,.right` ; updated my answer and the jsfiddle link

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Does display: table-cell overwrites the Bootstrap grid behaviour? Do you think is there a way that I can keep the Bootstrap grids and get the same result (without JQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and yes I have remove clearflex from parent element as it clear float for both child element. This increase and decrease it's hide when child element height increase and vise versa i.e. same for parent element.

```
  .outer{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background:yellow;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom:1px solid #111;
  display:table;
}
.outer > .right{
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  word-break : break-all;
}
.outer > .left{
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: I want my outer div to get one of its inner div height and changed accordingly. So when the outer div height changes the other inner div also has to change its height. But it won't.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Seems it won't help. I want in a scenario where  one of the inner div has a given height.  If I have to change your code .outer > .right{  height: 200px; } It is not working.

Comment: @bashi that's working it keeps your .outer height same as red of 200px; That's why I have assigned border-bottom to .outer div to see if it's height is increasing or not.

Comment: My final output should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/qjsqxk7j/31/
I tried your code didn't give me the expected o/p.

Comment: In that case, you have to apply 200px which you are applying to .right to .outer and .right and .left height to 100%.

Comment: just adding 200px .outer will do the work. I want a way that I don't need to give 200px to .outer class but can give 200px to .right class

Comment: Remove height from your .left add this jquery, $(document).ready(function(){
 var right = $(".right").css("height");
 $(".left").css({
   height : right
 });
});

Answer (score -1):

change some css Remove your Comment code

```
.right {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;

}
.left {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;      
}
.inner{
   position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.outer {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  max-width : 500px;
  height:200px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qjsqxk7j/25/

Comment: Thank you @Lalji for your reply. I want a way to do it without giving any height to the outer class. (The 'left' divs height is changing in my actual scenario, I want only left inner div to have a fixed height)

Comment: remove outer height & try

Comment: removing outer height you put ? then its the same code I put  as the question. It is not working.